# Changing Hover in ggplotly facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, facet

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
DATE<- as.Date(c('2016-11-17','2016-11-17','2016-11-17','2016-11-17', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-18','2016-11-18'))

TEST<-c('test', 'test','test','test','test','test','test','test')

TYPE<-c('type1', 'type1', 'type2', 'type2', 'type1', 'type1','type2', 'type2')

CATEGORY<-c('A', 'B','A', 'B','A', 'B','A', 'B' )

Revenue<-c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000)

df1<-data.frame(DATE, TEST, TYPE, CATEGORY, Revenue)

df1
        DATE TEST  TYPE CATEGORY Revenue
1 2016-11-17 test type1        A    1000
2 2016-11-17 test type1        B    2000
3 2016-11-17 test type2        A    3000
4 2016-11-17 test type2        B    4000
5 2016-11-18 test type1        A    5000
6 2016-11-18 test type1        B    6000
7 2016-11-18 test type2        A    7000
8 2016-11-18 test type2        B    8000
```

Then when I use the `plotly` function with `ggplot` (`ggplotly`) in order to do a facet_grid, it looks like below:

```
hp <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=DATE, y=Revenue)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") +  
facet_grid(`TYPE`~CATEGORY, scales = "free", space = "free") +
scale_y_continuous(name="Revenue", labels = dollar)
```

[image]

How do I change the hover section of this to show Revenue as a dollar amount? Also, a nice plus would also be how to change the coloring of the bar to represent the `DATE` variable.

Most importantly though I need to change the hover section so that the Revenue is represented as a dollar amount.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: The ggplotly(hp) should work, did you download plotly? And I have tried the fill = DATE, but that doesn't work either unfortunately @KiprasKančys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only suggest dirty work around

```
df1$Revenue2 <- df1$Revenue
df1$Revenue <- paste0(df1$Revenue2, '$')

hp <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=DATE, y=Revenue2, label = Revenue)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +  
    facet_grid(`TYPE`~CATEGORY, scales = "free", space = "free") +
    scale_y_continuous(name="Revenue") +
    theme(legend.position="none")

ggplotly(hp, tooltip = c("x", "label"))
```

Regarding coloring, for some reasons after I add `fill` parameter it removes hover text. That is strange.

Comment: The concept you gave worked, the only changed I made on my end was this to make it look alittle cleaner: `df1$Revenue <- dollar(df1$Revenue2)` thank you!